# Issue With SQL Pivot Function

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a SQL query where I am trying to replace null results with zero. My code is producing an error 
[1]: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
I am using an Oracle Database.

```
Select service_sub_type_descr,
nvl('Single-occupancy',0) as 'Single-occupancy',
nvl('Multi-occupancy',0) as 'Multi-occupancy'
From 
(select  s.service_sub_type_descr as service_sub_type_descr, ch.claim_id,nvl(ci.item_paid_amt,0) as item_paid_amt
from table_1 ch, table_" ci, table_3 s, table_4 ppd 
where ch.claim_id = ci.claim_id and ci.service_type_id = s.service_type_id 
and ci.service_sub_type_id = s.service_sub_type_id and ch.policy_no = ppd.policy_no) 
Pivot (
count(distinct claim_id), sum(item_paid_amt) as paid_amount For service_sub_type_descr IN ('Single-occupancy', 'Multi-occupancy')
)
```

Answer (score 3):

This expression:

```
 nvl('Single-occupancy',0) as 'Single-occupancy',
```

is using an Oracle bespoke function to say:  If the value of the string `Single-occupancy'` is not null then return the number `0`.

That logic doesn't really make sense.  The string value is never `null`.  And, the return value is sometimes a string and sometimes a number.  This should generate a type-conversion error, because the first value cannot be converted to a number.

I think you intend:

```
coalesce("Single-occupancy", 0) as "Single-occupancy",
```

The double quotes are used to quote identifiers, so this refers to the column called `Single-occupancy`.

All that said, **fix your data model**.  Don't have identifiers that need to be quoted.  You might not have control in the source data but you definitely have control within your query:

```
coalesce("Single-occupancy", 0) as Single_occupancy,
```

EDIT:

Just write the query using conditional aggregation and proper `JOIN`s:

```
select s.service_sub_type_descr, ch.claim_id,
       sum(case when service_sub_type_descr = 'Single-occupancy' then item_paid_amt else 0 end) as single_occupancy,
       sum(case when service_sub_type_descr = 'Multi-occupancy' then item_paid_amt else 0 end) as multi_occupancy
from table_1 ch join
     table_" ci
     on ch.claim_id = ci.claim_id join
     table_3 s
     on ci.service_type_id = s.service_type_id join
     table_4 ppd 
     on ch.policy_no = ppd.policy_no
group by s.service_sub_type_descr, ch.claim_id;
```

Much simpler in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the first part of the select but am now getting [1]: ORA-00904: "Multi-occupancy": invalid identifier

Comment: This query is not replacing blanks with 0's for me. I just ran it and still got the blanks

Answer (score 1):

for column aliases, you have to use double quotes !

don't use

```
 as 'Single-occupancy'
```

but :

```
 as "Single-occupancy",
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a different error message now? [1]: ORA-00904: "SERVICE_SUB_TYPE_DESCR": invalid identifier

Comment: better use Single_occupancy and Multi_occupancy for your column aliases (the part following the "as"), the part with "IN ('Single-occupancy', 'Multi-occupancy')" should not be changed I guess.

Comment: in the part with "s.service_sub_type_descr as service_sub_type_descr", you can remove the "as service_sub_type_descr" as you're reusing the same name, so it's not useful to add an alias there.

Comment: I removed the as service_sub_type_descr and same thing

Comment: Honnestly your query have several strange parts.

Select service_sub_type_descr,
nvl('Single-occupancy',0) as 'Single-occupancy',
nvl('Multi-occupancy',0) as 'Multi-occupancy'

=> the nvl('something',0) will always give you 'something', you also have to use a column or an expression as the 1st argument of the nvl function.

as for the PIVOT function I'm not an expert on this one

Comment: Can you explain? That is not very helpful

Comment: it's hard for me to guess what you want to do with your query and what are your data, so I cannot help more than that for the moment. I just replied about your first question which was about the misuse of quotes in a column alias.

Comment: I have a column of service sub types, I want to show the count of claims and sum of paid amount for the two service types. My problem is I am getting null blanks back and I want those to be zero